# How to be sure entity is persisted before calling another thread which queries this persisted entity?

Tags: java, multithreading, persistence, entitymanager, spring-transactions

I have the following situation in my Java web app (Spring + JPA):

1. I have method which persist an entity to the database
2. Right after persist entity, I call `notify()` which is waking up another thread.
3. The second thread is working with the entity i've just persisted.

So as a result I have:
Second thread queries a new-persisted entity, but it is not there yet. So second thread sends query to the database faster then main thread persist it. If i add some timeout it works perfectly. But it is not a suitable solution for me. I guess I can check entitymanager with `contains()` method. But I am not sure how efficient it will be. 
I am quite new in this subject, so I would be glad to hear your advices.

p.s. I am using Spring framework, so persist and notify happend in one transaction (marked with @Transactional annotation). second thread does not have any @Transactional classes.

Thanks, 
Emily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real persist to the database happens only after commit of the transaction, as far it happens in `@Transactional` method . So I needed to call second thread after transaction commit and I was able to do it using TransactionSynchronizationManager and its afterCommit() method. Here is the link with all info and examples http://azagorneanu.blogspot.ru/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html
Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Entity Listeners` for being notified when an entity is persisted. You can read about entity listeners in the [JPA Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events), the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html) and at [www.objectdb.com](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event).

Comment: Thank you, Katona. This solution didn't work for me but gave me an idea how to finally solve my problem. Entity Listeners didn't work because it was called inside one transaction and I still had the same problem. So I used TransactionSynchronizationManager, below I am going to describe it.